# Filling missing values of categorical values based on other categorical values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to fill missing values of categorical values in Pandas data frame with the most frequent values on another category. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'type': ['softdrink', 'juice', 'softdrink', 'softdrink',    'juice','juice','juice'],
    'product': ['coca', np.nan, 'pepsi', 'pepsi', 'orange','grape',np.nan], 
    'price': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70,50,60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

which results in

```
      price     | product   |   type    
0   25          |  coca     | softdrink   
1   94          |   NaN     | juice    
2   57          |   pepsi   | softdrink    
3   62          |   pepsi   | softdrink    
4   70          |   orange  | juice    
5   50          |    grape  | juice    
6   60          |   NaN     | softdrink
```

First, I use groupby as

```
df.groupby('type')['product'].value_counts()
```

to get

```
type      |   product    
juice     |    grape  |   1    
          |   orange  |   1    
softdrink | pepsi     |   2    
          | coca      |   1    
Name: product, dtype: int64
```

I want to fill a missing product of second row with "pepsi" (the most infrequence) but filling "grape" for missing value of row 6 of category "juice".
Without categorical group, my solution is to find most frequent value by the column and assign this value to missing value.

```
df['product'].fillna(df['product'].value_counts().index[0],inplace=True)
```

I struggle to complete the task since the return value of the command

```
df.groupby('type')['product'].value_counts()
```

is pandas series which can be accessed by

```
df.groupby('type')['product'].value_counts()['softdrink']['pepsi']
```

how I know which product+category has the most frequence.

Comment: Can you please not keep undoing all my formatting?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

Using `mode`

---

Data input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'type': ['softdrink', 'juice', 'softdrink', 'softdrink',    'juice','juice','softdrink'],
    'product': ['coca', np.nan, 'pepsi', 'pepsi', 'orange','grape',np.nan],
    'price': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70,50,60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

solution

```
df.groupby('type').product.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))

Out[28]: 
0      coca
1     grape
2     pepsi
3     pepsi
4    orange
5     grape
6     pepsi
Name: product, dtype: object
```

---

New df

```
df['product']=df.groupby('type').product.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
df
Out[40]: 
   price product       type
0     25    coca  softdrink
1     94   grape      juice
2     57   pepsi  softdrink
3     62   pepsi  softdrink
4     70  orange      juice
5     50   grape      juice
6     60   pepsi  softdrink
```

Comment: Wow! mode... real nice. I was planning on something similar but nowhere as nice as this.