# Filtering and filling Nan with mode in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have many qualitative variables in one column1 and corresponding qualitative values in another column which have blank values. I want to replace the blanks with the MODE value of each qualitative variable in column 1. For example if I have varibles such as Accountant, Engineer, Manager, etc. in column 1 and if I have Bachelor's degree as MODE for accountant, Master's for Engineer in column 2, I want to replace the coressponding blanks with Bachelor's and Master's Correctly. How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: please provide a [minimal&reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532986/filling-missing-values-of-categorical-values-based-on-other-categorical-values-i

Comment: @Shweta.Thanks. But I get an error stating that "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 23488 elements, new values have 23490 elements".

Answer (score 2):

df.loc[df["columnname"]==0,"columnname"]=np.nan

df["columnname"]=df.groupby("groupbycolumnname").columnname.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))